# Using parenthesis when calculating

Tags: php, math, brackets

I been looking around and noticed some people use parenthesis and some not when writing calculations/sums so was wondering what the difference is and what is the better option and why?

```
$foo = ($foobar * 100);
```

**or**

```
$foo = $foobar * 100;
```

Comment: bettr to use braces `(` to avoid confusion

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in this example. They just do it to follow [BODMAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mnemonics).
Using this is better as you are sure in longer calculations.

Comment: How is that connected to BODMAS?

Answer (score 1):

there is not any specific answer for this but AFAIT using braces `(` will avoid confusions while calculations.

read these useful links for more information

#### http://www.phpdeveloper.org.uk/articles/php-coding-guidelines/

#### http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html

#### http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php

Answer (score 1):

Parenthesis control the order of operations.

For instance in `$x * $y + 2`, multiplication will be executed before addition, so implicitly, there are parenthesis like this: `($x * $y) + 2`.

If you do not use parenthesis, operations will be carried out in the order as [defined](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operator) by the language, it is what is called operator precedence.

I suggest you always use parenthesis when you mix different operators in one expression (excluding assignment). Alternatively, you can break up your expression into multiple statements to give the elements that make up your calculation descriptive names.